# Progress Bar из картинок

Tags: c++, linux

Есть макет с `progressbar`´ом. Стоит он из 1. пустой шкалы (`bar.png`) и из ползунка (`prog.png`)

[image: макет]

Как написать данный фунционал без Qt: ползунок должен сначала заполнять нижнию шкаку, после заполнения, прибавляем несколько ползунков верхней шкалы и так, пока не заполнится верхняя.

Comment: Какой графический фреймворк используется? // и не знаю как вам, конечно, но мне такая анимация загрузки очень не нравится

Comment: Посмотрите исходники links2 — это такой текстово-графический браузер. Оно в качестве подложки может использовать directFB, который похож на небольшую обёртку над тем, чего вы пытаетесь достичь.